# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence

I am attempting to scan my entity class for JPA `@Column` annotation using the code below;

```
for (Method m : User.class.getMethods())
{
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(javax.persistence.Column.class))
    {
        javax.persistence.Column column = m.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Column.class);
        System.out.println(column.name());
    }
}
```

But I am getting below exception. I can confirm that I have javax-api jar loaded as part of my dependencies. Do anyone know what I am doing wrong?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code
>   attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/persistence/CascadeType     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:104)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:101)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.(AnnotationType.java:100)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:84)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:221)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:699)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:685)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.isAnnotationPresent(AccessibleObject.java:189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You jar does not contain any method bodies, but only the APIs specification. This is not suitable to use for running or deploying along with your application. Extract the jar open the class in a decompiler you will get to know why it is not running. I am not sure from where you get  javax-api jar but you surely need original full version of this jar.

Comment: +1: If you're using Eclipselink [try this one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence)

Comment: Juned, the better explanation would be that it's a API Specification instead of an API.

Comment: I resorted to glassfish implementation specific version of the API and that worked. Thanks to Juned and Aquillo.